# Can this String be created by shuffling these other two?

Tags: algorithm, combinatorics

Imagine my two friends `Wendy` and `Hunter` name their kid `Henry`.  Notice that the name `Henry` can be created from `Hunter` and from `Wendy` by merging subsets of the characters of each parent's name (without changing their order).  More specifically:

`"henry"` is `"hnr"` and `"ey"`, where the order of characters within each parent's name remains unchanged.

`"hnr"` is a subset of the characters in `"hunter"`, where the characters remain in order.

We can make a similar observation of `"ey"` and `"wendy"`.

**Question:**

Is there a simple way to verify whether any given name can be generated by two parent names without simply generating all the possible child names for a couple?

i.e. Can I easily check `isSpecialName("Dan", "Jane", "Adam")` - whether `"Dan"` can be created in such a fashion by the names `"Jane"` and `"Adam"`, without having to check it against all the merged ordered character subsets of `"Jane"` and `"Adam"`?

Comment: I believe you need to walk through the child name while maintaining indices in the parent names, and see if you can "assign" each letter to a parent's name, where "assigning" is the process of peeking ahead in the parent's name to see if you can find the character. The problem here is that you might need to backtrack if an ambiguous match (i.e. a character that is present in both parent's names) takes you down the wrong path.

Comment: Sure. Seems like a matter of checking the required letters against the available letters, checking among the given "source" words, and keeping an index into them to preserve the ordering requirement.

Comment: is "abcd" a special name of "ac" and "bd"? or special must be that the first half is from one name,  second half in another name?

Comment: @delta You are correct, "abcd" is a special name of "ac" and "bd" because the letters 'a' and 'c' appear in the same order in both "ac" and in "abcd".  Similarly, 'b' and 'd' appear in the same order in both "bd" and "abcd".

Comment: In any case, you have an approach-give it a shot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's say we want to justify if string `a` is special for string `b` and string `c`.

An important observation is, if `a` special for `b` and `c`, then remove the last character of `a`, got `a'`, it is still special for `b` and `c`. That is to say:

```
if   isSpecial(a,        b, c) is True
then isSpecial(a[0..-1], b, c) is True
```

This is a sub optimal pattern, so we can use dynamic programming algorithm.

Let `f(i, j, k)` represents if `a[0..i]` is special for `b[0..j]` and `c[0..k]`.

```
a[i] == b[j]  => f(i, j, k) sub pattern is f(i-1, j-1, k)
a[i] == c[k]  => f(i, j, k) sub pattern is f(i-1, j, k-1)
otherwise     => f(i, j, k) sub pattern is f(i, j, k-1) & f(i, j-1, k)
```

I have written a small c program to verify this algorithm. Code is not as concise as the algorithm though.

Time complexity `O(la*lb*lc)`, space complexity `O(la*lb*lc)`

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define MAX_LEN 10
#define SPECIAL '#'

bool f[MAX_LEN+1][MAX_LEN+1][MAX_LEN+1];

bool isSpecialName(char *pa, char *pb, char *pc) {
    int la = strlen(pa);
    int lb = strlen(pb);
    int lc = strlen(pc);

    if (la > lb + lc) return false;

    memset(f, false, sizeof(f));
    memset(f[0], true, sizeof(f[0]));

    for (int i=1; i<=la; ++i) for (int j=0; j<=lb; ++j) for (int k=0; k<=lc; ++k) {
        char a = tolower(pa[i-1]);
        char b = j > 0 ? tolower(pb[j-1]) : SPECIAL;
        char c = k > 0 ? tolower(pc[k-1]) : SPECIAL;

        if (j > 0)  f[i][j][k] = f[i][j-1][k]   || f[i][j][k];
        if (k > 0)  f[i][j][k] = f[i][j][k-1]   || f[i][j][k];
        if (a == b) f[i][j][k] = f[i-1][j-1][k] || f[i][j][k];
        if (a == c) f[i][j][k] = f[i-1][j][k-1] || f[i][j][k];
    }

    return f[la][lb][lc];
}

void check(char *a, char *b, char *c) {
    if (isSpecialName(a, b, c)) fprintf(stdout, "'%s' *IS* special name of '%s' and '%s'\n", a, b, c);
    else fprintf(stderr, "'%s' is *NOT* special of '%s' and '%s'\n", a, b, c);
}

int main() {
    check("ab", "a", "b");
    check("Dan", "Jane", "Adam");
    check("Henry", "Hunter", "Wendy");
    check("abcd", "ac", "bd");
    check("abcd", "ac", "bb");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are only two or less possibilities when you start matching from the start: either take the first occurrence in mother's or in father's name. Later occurrences could also work, but if they do, taking the first occurence has to work too. So we can write a pretty simple algorithm:

```js
function isSpecialName(child, mother, father) {
    child = child.toLowerCase();
    mother = mother.toLowerCase();
    father = father.toLowerCase();
    for (let i = 0, x = 0, y = 0; i < child.length; i++) {
        let m = mother.indexOf(child[i], x), f = father.indexOf(child[i], y);
        if (m < 0 && f < 0)
            return false;    
        if (f < 0)
            x = m + 1;
        else if (m < 0)
            y = f + 1;
        else if (isSpecialName(
                    child.substr(i + 1), mother.substr(m + 1), father.substr(y)))
            return true;
        else
            y = f + 1;
    }
    return true;
}
```